# What am I supposed to see through the Telescope on A Reasonable Man - Tier 3?

Tags: the-secret-world

I'm working on the quest **A Reasonable Man** on The Savage Coast. I've just reached Tier 3, and I've been directed to '*Use a Telescope*'.

Easy enough, I've found the scope, and if I pan around, I can see a big Zombie dude down on the beach. Seems simple enough, but the quest doesn't update.

I've asked around in General Chat, and the answer I've gotten is 'click a whole bunch near the filth spout.' Now, I've spent the last month playing a whole lot of [diablo-3](/questions/tagged/diablo-3). My clicking skills are the stuff of legend, and I have *clicked the hell* out of every pixel near that filth spout.

What am I missing here? Is this one of the many quests where quest objects become non-interactive and I can resolve it via shard-hopping? Or am I just completely missing the point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this is bugged, but not to the extent that some other quests are.  I'd try instance-hopping.

> You're supposed to be clicking on/around the barrels/spout.

Comment: I'd add that I just ran this again last night and it triggered the moment I clicked anywhere near the correct area while zoomed in.

Comment: Clicking did the trick for me as well.

Comment: Had exactly the same problem, just spam clicked around the barrels thanks to this post :)

Comment: for me this worked basically instantly when i zoomed all the way in

Answer (score 3):

Are you multi-monitor resolution?  It's bugged at the very high res'es.  If so, drop down to a single monitor resolution and complete it on one screen.

Comment: I'm not, (1440x800) and spamming the barrels eventually worked for me but +1 for useful info.

Comment: Yeah, there are problems with some of the UI elements at those resolutions being misaligned to mouse clicks, so this actually doesn't surprise me.  Good info.